# check file exists once in n mins c++

Tags: c++

i have created a class which reads a file and does some operations on the contents and saves a new file with time stamp. But, i am in a requirement to perform in such a way that , a code should check every one min whether the file is present. If yes, it should process the file. It need to work on cross platform.

I am novice in c++ and need to know what approach i need to follow for this. Do i need to create process or something. I am completely blank .

```
class inputHandler
{
public:

void readInput();
void performTask();
void saveFile();
};
```

since the code implementation is too large, just i am posting the structure. I am ready to spend time on this. So, i need a sample tutorial which can guide me to achieve this .

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the environment. Do you need cross-platform? Is C++11 OK? Is boost OK?

Comment: On what operating system? With Linux you might use the `access` system call. And you might want to use `inotify` to be notified when e.g. it is removed or touched.

Comment: yeah, i ve edited my post.. i need a cross platform implementation.

Comment: please ignore if i am being so stupid in this question. "do i need to create a process of my own which checks every n mins"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not addressed by the C++ standard. Thus, you'll have to implement code for each supported system, or use a library.

As far as I understood, the most general solution is to create a thread which loops every minute, checking file timestamps. Naturally, depending on your code, you could do it another way, avoiding threads whatsoever. Using a notification system such as `inotify` could be much better. Also, you could use `alarm()` on POSIX-compatible systems, being alarmed whenever a minute has passed.

Anyway, if you go with the thread solution, in POSIX-compatible systems, check out `pthread_create()` and `stat()`. In Windows, check out `CreateThread()` and `GetFileTime()`. To have a one-minute delay, `sleep(60000)` or `Sleep(60000)` respectively should do the trick.

Just to clarify, "to create a process" is system's programming jargon meaning roughly "to launch a new program" (or "thread", sometimes). In that sense, if you follow the above you'll be creating a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

The simple part is checking if a file exists: when you open an `std::ifstream` it will be in good state only if the file exists:

```
std::ifstream in(filename);
if (in) {
    // the file exists and can be processed here
}
```

The more interesting part is to do something in regular intervals. The basic idea is to set up a timer in some form. Depending on whether anything else needs to be done you may need a separate thread: if the program just waits until the file exists and doesn't do anything in the mean time, you can just sleep and there is no need to spawn another thread. Otherwise, you probably want to spawn a thread which is just sleeping.

Assuming you need to use a separate thread, you probably want to be able to interrupt it from waiting, e.g., to exit in a clean way upon condition from a separate thread. thus, I would use a condition variable with a timed wait, i.e., something like this:

```
std::mutex              guard;
std::condition_variable condition;
bool                    done(false);

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(guard);
while (!done) {
    condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::minutes(n));
    if (!done) {
        do_whatever_needs_to_be_done_once_every_n_minutes();
    }
}
```

The code above uses C++ 2011 facilities. If you can't use the corresponding classes, you can use suitable alternatives, e.g., the [Boost](http://boost.org) classes.